# MongoDB how can i use $center in a location array inside an object whit a non unique name key

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i would appreciate if someone could help me with this and sorry for my bad english D:

i have this objects in my mongo scooters table and i want to get all the scooters in a radius of X miles
[objects in mongo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZRa.png)

the problem that i have is, i have objects with keys like scooter/1, scooter/2, scooter/3 and i want to use $center with the location  array inside each object and i dont really know how to code the find method to make this work, i actually do something like this 
[client query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkNZv.png)

and didnt work, i thing the problem is the slash-id in the object name like scooter/3, scooter/1 and i dont really know how to workaround this,
i know the code its wrong and i wold appreciate help :D

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: Hi, im using mongodb package, i use it with MongoClient.connect()

Comment: the reason  its because im using mongodb as storage for deepstream server that saves the position record of each scooter on mongodb scooter table directly

Comment: maybe the problem is because im saving the records with the name scooter/id but i tried saving them with the name scooter without slash id and didnt work as spected because when another scooter saves his record, overrides the another record data i dont really know the correct usage for this case